# Solve a system of two linear equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

If $2x+3y =\frac{1}{10}$ and $3x+2y = \frac{1}{8}$, then how to calculate here $x$ and $y$?

I know it is easy but not for me so please describe your solution in step by step. Thanks for your help.

Answers are $x=\frac{7}{200}$ and $y = \frac{1}{100}$.

Comment: First of all, do you know how to solve systems of equations?

Comment: what do you know about systems of equations, and substitution of variables? The standard method says to choose one of the equations and express one of its variables in terms of the other, then substitute this expression in the other equation.

Comment: @mau Can you please tell me how to post question on this site in the format in which you edited it. Actually i don't know how to put maths term in this format.

Comment: @Androiddeveloper it's MathJax, a formatting system with a syntax similar to TeX. See http://www.mathjax.org/about/ . Keep in mind that mathematicians are used to TeX: this is why here in math.SE it is common. Other formatting options may be found at http://math.stackexchange.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{r}
2x+3y=1/10; \\
3x+2y=1/8; \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Multiple $1$st equation by $3$, multiple $2$nd  equation by $2$ (to get the same coeffficients near $x$):

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{r}
6x+9y=3/10; \\
6x+4y=1/4; \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Then we subtract  equations:

$$(6x+9y)-(6x+4y)=3/10-1/4;$$
$$5y=6/20-5/20=1/20;$$
$$y=1/100.$$

Then substitute $y$ into $1$st equation (you can substitute into $2$nd equation too):

$$2x+3\cdot 1/100 = 1/10;$$
$$2x=1/10-3/100 = 10/100-3/100=7/100;$$
$$x=7/200.$$

Solution: $x=7/200, y=1/100$.

Comment: ok ok now i get it. Thanks for clarify it.

Answer (score 0):

okay , elementary.
$ 2x + 3y = 1/10$ , take that 10 to the LHS and rewrite as

$ 20x + 30y $ = $1$

then similarly ,  $ 3x+2y = 1/8 $

becomes $24x+16y = 1$

$24x+16y = 1$---------1

$ 20x + 30y $ = $1$ ----------2

multiply 1 by the coeff of x in the next eqn 2 (i.e here 20)

and 2 by the coeff of x in 1    ( here 24) $.

so your eqns become

$ 480x + 320y = 20 $

$480x + 720 y= 24 $

subtract these eqns and we get

$ 400 y = 4  => y = 1/100 $

put the value of y in any one eqn to get $x = 7/{200} $